# Ignore some comments

Tags: doxygen

I am working with some legacy code, for which I am generating XML documentation using doxygen. I have two problems with this kind of code. First it contains invalid comments. For example:

```
///@struct E  
enum E  
{
 E1, E2, E3;  
};
```

This causes doxygen to generate output for struct with name `E`, which is not in the code. My second problem is with HTML links. For example, for the following input:

```
///@brief For info about this struct see: <a href="http://www.foo.com/bar&bar"\>  
struct S
{
  int i;
}
```

the doxygen generated output is not a valid XML because the `&` in the link is not properly escaped.

For the above reasons I would like doxygen to ignore some comments. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that doxygen has a simple switch for this, however, you can write your own [INPUT_FILTER](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter) program to clean up the file (by stripping out comments, for example) before doxygen runs.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed and tested that html comments within a doxygen comment will be ignored:

```
///@brief some comment here <--! ignored here --> also continues over.
```

As far as the & not being escaped, have you noticed \& would escape it?  Maybe this is a solution for that part.

Comment: Does it work if you change it to: ##@brief some comment here <--! ignored here --> also continues over.